# Showing combined results for graph from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**VOTES**

```
ID |  YEARMONTH | VOTES
========================
1  | 201101     | 23
1  | 201102     | 12
1  | 201103     | 12
2  | 201101     | 15
3  | 201102     | 1
4  | 201102     | 17
```

**LECTURES**

```
ID |  YEARMONTH | LECTURES
========================
1  | 201101     | 1
2  | 201101     | 2
3  | 201102     | 5
```

Assuming that an ID can have no rows for each of the tables for a given yearmonth (either lectures or votes), I need to list the results so I can show them in a graph.

**If for a yearmonth a result is missing on the other table, I need to     display zero.**

So that the result should look like this:

```
ID |  YEARMONTH | VOTES | LECTURES
==================================
1  | 201101     | 23    | 1
1  | 201102     | 12    | 0
1  | 201103     | 12    | 0
```

But of course, if VOTES were missing where LECTURES are not missing, I would need to display a 0 there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a subquery with all the possible ID/YearMonth combinations, and then `LEFT JOIN` on the other tables.  Then use `COALESCE` to return 0 if the corresponding records are null:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.YearMonth, COALESCE(V.Votes,0) Votes, COALESCE(L.Lectures,0) Lectures
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, YearMonth
    FROM Votes
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, YearMonth
    FROM Lectures 
    ) t
    LEFT JOIN Votes v on t.ID = v.ID AND t.YearMonth = v.YearMonth
    LEFT JOIN Lectures l on t.ID = l.ID AND t.YearMonth = l.YearMonth
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04cb6/2)

Comment: this seems a good approach, but the YEARMONTH is not linear. I need the YEARMONTH to be distinct to be able to use the data for the graph

Comment: @Ted -- I may need you to elaborate -- from your above data, what are your desired results?  Are you not wanting t.Id in your results?  Perhaps removing and then adding a SUM and/or GROUP BY can accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Eventually I used SUMs with GROUP BY as you suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a FULL OUTER JOIN for this, but MySQL doesn't support them.

You can emulate it with a UNION, however, as the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql) shows.